# Lunch possibilities and permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Problem: Owners of a restaurant advertise that they offer 1,114,095 different lunches based on the fact that they have 16 "free fixins" to go along with any of their 17 menu items (sandwiches, hot dogs, and salads). How did they arrive at that number?

This is a precalculus textbook exercise for which the answer is provided in the back of the book.  It's in the "Permutations" section.

My first thought was to sum up the number of possibilities of choosing no toppings, of choosing one topping, of choosing two toppings, and so on, but that is not practical.

So instead I think of event one as choosing a menu item with 17 possible outcomes.  Then event two is whether I put topping #1 on so there are two outcomes.  Event three is whether I put topping #2 on so there are two outcomes.  And so on.  So there are a sequence of 17 events.

By the fundamental counting principle I get that the number of lunches is

$$
17 \cdot 2^{16}
$$

but the back of the book shows

$$
17 \cdot (2^{16} - 1)
$$.

Is it possible that they are not considering the event of no toppings?  I mean are toppings required or something?

Comment: Given that the problem starts by telling you the answer (and that the answer is odd), it must be the case that they're excluding some possibility.  But your approach is correct, and I think your answer is better than the restaurant's for precisely the reason you state.